# NodeJS global variable not reassignable

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I am trying to unit test code that uses JavaScript library that is set a global variable if it does not exist. The pattern the library is using is:

`var GLOBAL_VAR = GLOBAL_VAR || {}`

This works in browser world, but when I execute the code in NodeJS, it does not work. The problem comes down to this:

```
var myGlobal = 'CORRECT';
console.log('Prints CORRECT', myGlobal || 'WRONG');
(function () {
  // Why does this print WRONG?
  var myGlobal = myGlobal || 'WRONG';
  console.log('Prints WRONG', myGlobal);
}).call(this);

(function () {
  console.log('Prints CORRECT', myGlobal || 'WRONG');
}).call(this);
```

Why is the first function printing WRONG while the second function prints CORRECT?

Comment: That’s because you’re _declaring_ a new `myGlobal` at the same time. Your function body is equivalent to `var myGlobal; myGlobal = myGlobal || 'WRONG'; console.log('Prints WRONG', myGlobal);`. At the second statement, `myGlobal` is `undefined`. Don’t declare it inside, i.e. don’t use `var`.

Comment: Also note that your provided code snippet works the same way in both browser and Node.js environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a local variable `myGlobal` inside the first anonymous function. This shadows the global variable.

Then, in the anonymous function, you declare:

```
var myGlobal = myGlobal || 'WRONG';
//             ^
//             |  this local variable is undefined here, as
//                the global is not accessible with this name
```

That is why `myGlobal` (the local variable) gets the value `'WRONG'`.

The solution is to rename the confusingly named local variable `myGlobal` in the anonymous function to something that does not shadow the global variable.

Note that you would not have this problem if you used `let` as `let` does not allow you to use the variable as a value in it's own declaration:

```
let x = x || 'WRONG'; // should produce an error and leave x undefined.
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to test the Phaser library by breaking the source into a couple parts and setting global variables in between.